# Flask-socketio messages not being received when sent from worker script to web script

Tags: flask, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am using flask-socketio to implement websockets on my Flask app. An intensive function runs on a worker script and is supposed to emit a message to the websocket when it is complete. This message should then be received by the client and used to update the display.

The trouble I'm having is that messages sent from the worker script do not get received by the client. The same messages sent from within the Flask app are received. I assume the problem is that the two different scripts have different websocket connections; how do I make them talk to each other?

**worker.py (running outside of Flask app) - this does not get received by client**

```
socketio.emit('edit_plan', {'data': 'testing test'})
```

**main.py (running inside Flask app) - this does get received by client**

```
@app.route("/home", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
@register_breadcrumb(app, '.', 'Home')
def home():
    # Send websocket test message
    print("Emitting test messages")
    socketio.emit('edit_plan', {'data': 'testing test'})
```

**Front end**

```
componentDidMount() {
    const that = this ;

    // Connect to websocket and await message
    const socket = io();

    socket.on('connect', function() {
      console.log("Connected to websocket")
      console.log(socket.id)
    });

    socket.on('edit_plan', function(msg, cb) {
      console.log(msg)
      alert(msg)
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you followed the documentation to set up your worker as an external emitter?

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg Is that the section entitled 'Emitting from an External Process'? I've just found that in the last few minutes and am reading it now.

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to get it to work by adding Redis and a channel name to my SocketIO constructor: `socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*", message_queue=os.environ.get('REDIS_URL'), channel='channel_name')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Miguel for his comment (and, indeed, for his excellent Flask support all over the web!)

The solution is to add a `message_queue` and a `channel` to the SocketIO constructor. For example:

```
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*", 
message_queue=os.environ.get('REDIS_URL'), channel='channel_name')
```

Comment: I recommend you use the default channel. The only thing you need in most cases is to provide the URL to your message queue.

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg Thanks. I did find that it only worked when I added both the message queue URL and a channel name. 

However, I've subsequently changed tack and abandoned socketio for a while, as I was hitting all sorts of problems running it on Heroku (my brain started to hurt when I began reading about monkey patching etc!)